# Logo does not center in Firefox but centers in Chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox, stylesheet

This is my site in question: [**LINK**](http://tubebackgrounds.co.uk/portfolio/)

As you can see, my Logo is pushed over to the ***right side*** in Firefox but it should be centered. Works great in Chrome for example.

I've tried looking for a Firefox only stylesheet, but I couldn't really find the right CSS setting that makes this work correctly.

**Here's the relevant HTML code that's wrapped in a `id` named `container` that I have so far:**

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul id="index_cards">
    <li id="card-1">
        <h3><strong>Home</strong></h3>
    </li>
    <li id="card-2">
        <h3><strong>About/Contact</strong></h3>
    </li>
    <li id="card-4">
        <h3><strong>Portfolio</strong></h3>
    </li>
    <li id="card-5">
        <h3><strong>Services</strong></h3>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="imgs/logo.png" name="ielogo" width="457" height="223" id="ielogo" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
  top:-73px;
  margin-top:-70px;
  min-height:100%;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
}

#header {
  margin-top:-30px;
  height:250px;
  background-image:url(../imgs/header-top.png);
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  padding:10px;
}

#logo {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:457px;
  height:223px;
}
```

Comment: so where should your logo actually be? looks fine for me in ff12

Comment: I'm using FF12 and it is off-centre. The CSS for div id `logo` looks fine. I think you just need to replace the `img` html with css instead.

Comment: those images that enlarge on mouseover are really cool because they are transparent! how did u do that?

Comment: @Артём Царионов, that appears to be a empty `div` of specific dimensions with `border` applied. Since the text is selectable, the entire `div` also has CSS3 `rotate` as well.

Comment: As written, this question will be useless once answered (as i presume you're going to fix the error, so future visitors won't see the problem that was solved).  Please edit the question to include the relevant code.  A screenshot of the actual visible output (with anomalies highlighted by freehand circles, if possible :)) would be helpful as well.

Comment: As far as I can see the problem is that "margin:auto" in ff results to 0px

Comment: Besides that problem, you should add a standard fallback for all those prefixed CSS properties: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/07/aurora-16-is-out/

Comment: @arttronics well what ever it is, i am going to copy it

Comment: @cHao, I've updated this Question so it has future usability. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem lies with image put this in css

```css
#logo img { display: block; }
```

http://jsbin.com/afuquq/3/

Answer (score 0):

**Revised answer:** The solution is to incorporate the `logo` into the `navigation` section ***and*** have `#header` placed with `position:absolute;` on webpage.

**HTML Fragment:**

```html
<div id="header"></div>

     <div id="container">

       <div id="nav">

          <ul id="index_cards">
             <li id="card-1">
                 <h3><strong>Home</strong></h3>

             </li>
             <li id="card-2">
                 <h3><strong>About/Contact</strong></h3>

             </li>
             <li id="card-4">
                 <h3><strong>Portfolio</strong></h3>

             </li>
             <li id="card-5">
                 <h3><strong>Services</strong></h3>

             </li>
          </ul>

          <div id="logo"></div>

       </div>

     <!-- continued-->

     </div>
```

**CSS:**

```CSS
/* This section is modified */
#header {
    background-image:url(http://tubebackgrounds.co.uk/portfolio/imgs/header-top.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

/* This section is modified. */
#logo {
    background-image:url(http://tubebackgrounds.co.uk/portfolio/imgs/logo.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:457px;
    height:250px;
}
```

There is also extra addition of `margin-top: -20px;` applied to CSS Selector `#body` to compensate for separate `@font-face` issue when those fonts are not loaded. Still, font integration will need to be addressed correctly.

**Note:** The jsFiddle below will not render `@font-face` fonts due to security settings.

Reference: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9VjBW/show/)

***Access the above jsFiddle without `/show/` in Address Bar to view the Edit Page.***